# Magento2 : What is the difference between Order Status And Order State

Tags: magento2, orders, status, state

Does anyone know how we can differenciate Order Status And Order State ?

Comment: have a look at https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-difference-between-magento-order-status-and-order-state.html and https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-order-status-order-state.html

Comment: Can you specify what you are looking for? Means what you want to achive?

Comment: i am little bit confused why magento uses both status as well as state , thats why , i wants to know what actually state and status is .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `order state` and `order status` are usually mixed up since their names and functions are similar.

An order state is a position of an order in the current processing flow. Magento has the following pre-defines order states:

```
New
Pending Payment
Processing
Complete
Closed
Canceled
On Hold
Payment Review
```

Each order state can have one or more order statuses assigned to it. This makes processing easier.

For example, a “Pending Payment” order state can have the following order statuses:

```
Pending Payment Paypal
Pending Payment Card
Pending Payment Store Credit
```

Magento provides a way for create custom order statuses. For this:

```
1. Admin Panel>System>Order Statuses;
2. click the "Create New Status" button;
3. fill necessary information in the "New Order Status" page;
4. click "Save Status";
5. assign a recently created  status to a particular order state.
```

Comment: Cite your sources: https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-difference-between-magento-order-status-and-order-state.html

Comment: Thanks @Dhiren Vasoya , i think now i am clear about state and status

Comment: great, if answer help you mark as solution so it will help other in community.

Comment: and @FabianSchmengler , i think it is better that he does't paste link directly ,but he explain me in their way , so this is matter.

Comment: @SanjayShiyal the answer is a plain copy/paste, it doesn’t explain anything more.

Answer (score 2):

> The “order state” and “order status” are usually mixed up since their
> names and functions are quite similar.
>
> - 1,Order Status. All orders have an order status that is associated with a stage in the order processing workflow
> - 1,An order state is a position of an order in the curent processing flow.
> - 2,Magento Order State  is used to define processing order
> - 2,Magento Order Status is used by the administrator to know the exact order flow

[Source](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-difference-between-magento-order-status-and-order-state.html)

Answer (score 1):

The order status is just a label for the order state. It doesn't represent any logic or workflow. 
You could even assign the "status" closed for pending payments.

If you have PayPal, CC and Checkmo as Payment options, you might want to assign different order statuses for each of those when there's a pending payment. Like pending CC, pending Paypal etc.